# Is there is any way to change or overwrite the bootstrap "@media" to "@media screen and () {}"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

My application requires that some of the classes inside bootstrap media query not affect the screen when in print mode. I do not want to apply `bootstrap media CSS` to print mode. This happens as bootstrap classes are written inside `"@media () {}"`. It would be better if we have those classes inside `"@media screen and () {}"`. Is there an efficient way to apply styles to `"@media screen and () {}"` without modifying bootstrap CSS itself or by overwriting the codes?